# How do I overwrite values I select from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

For examples this does not work:

```
mtcars %>%
filter(cyl == 8) %>%
select(mpg) <- 1
```

I would like to replace all the values I selected with 1

I want to replace everything and not only selected values, so I am not sure how to use `replace`

Comment: Can you give a clearer English-language explanation of what you are trying to do?  The first part of your calculation is reducing mtcars to the mean values of hp for each value of `cyl`. Then what?  Which values are you trying to replace with 1?

Comment: Sorry, I posted a dumb example. I basically want to select multiple values from the dataframe and replace them.

I changed the example to make more sense

Comment: How about `mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 8] <- 1` ?

Comment: @AllanCameron How does that work with multipe conditions?

e.g `mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 6 | 4] <- 6`

Comment: `mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 6 | mtcars$cyl == 4] <- 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = ifelse(cyl == 8, 1, cyl))
```

To walk you through: the code tells `R` to

1. `mtcars` - take the dataset `mtcars`
2. `%>%` - pass it to `mutate()`
3. `mutate()` - change values
4. `mutate(mpg = ...)` - change values in the column `mpg`
5. `mpg = ifelse(...)` - set values of `mpg` depending on a condition
6. `ifelse(cyl == 8, 1, cyl)` - if the value of `cyl` is equal to `8`, return `1`; otherwise return the value of `cyl`
7. together: `mutate(mpg = ifelse(cyl == 8, 1, cyl)` - set the values of `mpg` to `1` in rows where the `cyl`-column is equal to `8`; in all other cells, leave `mpg` unaltered.

Important: this only returns the altered dataset. If you want to actually save these changes, you need to **assign** the result to an(other) object, e.g. like this:

```
mtcars_updated <- mtcars %>%
    mutate(mpg = ifelse(cyl == 8, 1, cyl))
```

[Edit] As correctly highlighted in the comments: you can also use the `%<>%` operator to manipulate an object and assign the result to the initial object. For your example:

```
mtcars  %<>%
    mutate(mpg = ifelse(cyl == 8, 1, cyl))
```

However, this is less explicit code and discouraged in the [tidyverse style guide](https://%20https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html) (see section " 4.6 Assignment")
[End of edit]

Hope this helps!

**P.S.:** if you have a *more complex conditional structure*, `ifelse` isn't great. It'd be better to use `case_when()` (ensure to also include a condition that is `TRUE ~ cyl` in the end).

Comment: You can also use `%<>%` to mutate *and* assign, but it's a less common idiom (so will be harder for others to read)

Comment: Yes. However, it's less explicit and discouraged in the tidyverse style guide (https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html, see 4.6). I added it to the response, however.